# Get filelist for offline html 5/js app

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game in JS with Phaser.io and using Web2Executable to run it on desktops. I'm making a lot of test files during development and every time I add a file or remove one I have to manually add/remove code. Is there a way I can just get a list of all the files in my working directory/subfolders? I can then load them up by file extension no problem... but I've been googling for half an hour and I can't work out how to get a filelist without making everything crazy complicated.

Comment: There is no way a browser is letting you do that, for security reasons. You should consider hybrid apps like: nw.js or electron. And therefore, there is no viable answer to this question.

Comment: One possible solution would be a build system that gleans all the files in your directories and processes either their contents or filenames and packages them into whatever thing you are having to alter manually.  There isn't really a native way to do this "*without making everything crazy complicated*".

Answer (score 0):

Client-side Javascript cannot read the contents of a directory.

I think is the best form to read directory is a back-end language like php and return a object json then you acess this page with ajax and get this object